# Using SPM5 with MatLab

Tags: porting, matlab

I am trying to use SPM5, but  I have the latest version of MatLab, which does not work with SPM5.  The last version of MatLab SPM5 works with is 7.3.  Is there a way to downgrade MatLab, or a quick way to port SPM5 over to the current version of MatLab?

I cannot use SPM8 because it does not have the Lateralization Index (LI) tool that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have you tried using SPM5 with a more recent version of Matlab?  The FIL website simply says that they cannot predict how SPM5 will run on versions after 7.1, not that they are incompatible.  I have personally used SPM5 with R2008b (7.7) for years without a problem.

Second, versions after R2008b/7.7 deprecated the call finite() in favor of isfinite().  This caused SPM5 to stop working.  I was able to use SPM5 with R2010b (7.11) by replacing all calls to finite() with isfinite().  I don't know if this same strategy would work for more recent versions of Matlab, but it might be worth a shot.

Third, I do know that different versions of Matlab can be installed at the same time.  So, if you have a maintenance agreement that allows you to obtain older versions of the software you should be able to install them concurrently without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a licence for MATLAB that is in maintenance, you have a licence for all previous versions of MATLAB. You should be able to download any recent version by logging on to your MathWorks account. If you need an older version than is available via the website, or have difficulty accessing the version you want, contact MathWorks support directly.